# Couldn't find with 'id'の解決方法（ショッピングカート機能の実装）

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

現在RailsでECサイトを作成中です。
カート機能を実装したいのですが、「カートに追加」のボタンをクリックすると、以下のエラーが発生します。
LineItemが判別できないというエラーと認識しております。
application.controller.rbに
include CurrentCart
before_action :set_cart　
の記述を追加しましたが、変化はありませんでした。

また、「カートに追加」のパスにはidも渡しております。
binding.pryで検証したところ、
@line_itemの値はnilとなっておりました。
解決方法の見当がつかず、情けないですが何卒お力添えの程宜しくお願い致します。

### Error message

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /line_items/2
Couldn't find LineItem with 'id'=2
```

## line_items.controller

```
class LineItemsController < ApplicationController
 include CurrentCart
 before_action :set_line_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
 before_action :set_cart, only: [:create]

 
 def index
   @line_items = LineItem.all
 end

 def show
 end

 def new
   @line_item = LineItem.new
 end

 def edit
 end

  def create
   item = Item.find(params[:item_id])
   @line_item = @cart.add_item(item)

   respond_to do |format|
     if @line_item.save
       format.html { redirect_to @line_item.cart, notice: 'カゴに追加されました' }
       format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @line_item }
     else
       format.html { render :new }
       format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
   end
 end

 def update
   respond_to do |format|
     if @line_item.update(line_item_params)
       format.html { redirect_to @line_item, notice: 'Line item was successfully updated.' }
       format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @line_item }
     else
       format.html { render :edit }
       format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
   end
 end

 
 def destroy
   @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
   @line_item.destroy
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html { redirect_to cart_path(@cart), notice: 'Line item was successfully destroyed.' }
     format.json { head :no_content }
   end
 end

 private
   def set_line_item     #it says I have a problem here
     @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
   end

   def line_item_params
     params.require(:line_item).permit(:item_id)
   end
end
```

## current_cart.rb

```
module CurrentCart
  private
  def set_cart
    @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecoedNotFound
    @cart = Cart.create
    session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
  end
end
```

## application.controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  include CurrentCart
  before_action :set_cart
 
end
```

## routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :line_items
  resources :carts
  resources :items
  devise_for :users, controllers:{
  registrations: 'registrations'
  }
  root 'items#index'
  devise_scope :user do
    get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
  end
end
```

## show.html.rb(長いため省略しています）

```
<div class="column is-3 is-offset-1">
      <div class="bg-white pa4 border-radius-3">
        <h4 class="title is-5 has-text-centered"><%= number_to_currency(@item.price) %></h4>
        <p class="has-text-centered mb4">出品者： <%= @item.user.name %></p>
        <%= button_to '買い物カゴに追加する',line_item_path(item_id:@item), class: 'button is-warning add-to-cart' %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

## line_item.rb

```
class LineItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :cart
end
```

## item.rb

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  before_destroy :not_refereced_by_any_line_item
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
  has_many :line_items
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

validates :title, :brand, :price, :model, presence: true
validates :description, length: {maximum:1000, too_long: "%{count} 文字以内でお願いします。"}
validates :title, length: {maximum:100, too_long: "%{count} 文字以内でお願いします。"}

  BRAND = %w{ a b c d e }
  FINISH = %w{ 1週間以内 1ヶ月以内 1年以内 それ以前  }
  CONDITION = %w{ 新品 やや傷あり 傷あり かなり傷あり }

  private
  def not_refereced_by_any_line_item
    unless line_item.empty?
      errors.add(:base, "line items present")
      throw :abort
    end
  end
end
```

## cart.rb

```
class Cart < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy 

  def add_item(item)
    current_item = line_items.find_by(item_id: item.id)
      if current_item
        current_item.increment(:quantity)
      else
        current_item = line_items.build(item_id: item.id)
      end
    current_item
  end
end
```

## Server Log

```
Started POST "/line_items/2?item_id=2" for ::1 at 2019-10-23 18:04:28 +0900
   (0.4ms)  SET NAMES utf8,  @@SESSION.sql_mode = CONCAT(CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',STRICT_ALL_TABLES'), ',NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'),  @@SESSION.sql_auto_is_null = 0, @@SESSION.wait_timeout = 2147483
   (0.3ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.`version` FROM `schema_migrations` ORDER BY `schema_migrations`.`version` ASC
  
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/line_items/2"):
  
actionpack (6.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:36:in `call'
web-console (4.0.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:132:in `call_app'
web-console (4.0.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (4.0.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `catch'
web-console (4.0.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
railties (6.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (6.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (6.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (6.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
activesupport (6.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `tagged'
railties (6.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (6.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:126:in `call'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:83:in `call'
webpacker (4.0.7) lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:29:in `perform_request'
rack-proxy (0.6.5) lib/rack/proxy.rb:57:in `call'
railties (6.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:526:in `call'
puma (3.12.1) lib/puma/configuration.rb:227:in `call'
puma (3.12.1) lib/puma/server.rb:660:in `handle_request'
puma (3.12.1) lib/puma/server.rb:474:in `process_client'
puma (3.12.1) lib/puma/server.rb:334:in `block in run'
puma (3.12.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:135:in `block in spawn_thread'
Started GET "/line_items/2?item_id=2" for ::1 at 2019-10-23 18:04:52 +0900
Processing by LineItemsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"item_id"=>"2", "id"=>"2"}
  LineItem Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `line_items`.* FROM `line_items` WHERE `line_items`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:61:in `set_line_item'
Completed 404 Not Found in 87ms (ActiveRecord: 3.5ms | Allocations: 20765)



ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find LineItem with 'id'=2:
  app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:61:in `set_line_item'

Started POST "/__better_errors/691901ca03d27e6b/variables" for ::1 at 2019-10-23 18:04:53 +0900
S
```

Comment: エラーメッセージの意味は LineItem モデルの id = 2 がありません。って意味ですね。
LineItem モデルの作成にどこかしらで失敗しているのだと思います。

カート追加の URL や、そのコントローラー、モデルの詳細などもわかるともう少しちゃんと回答できると思います。

Comment: @HAZI コメントありがとうございます。モデルのコードやエラーログを追加致しました。恐れ入りますが、精査して頂けると大変助かります。モデル同士の結びつけに問題はないと思うのですが、どうでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`No route matches [POST] "/line_items/2"` と書いてありますね。

そのようなルートはないとのことなので、

`http://localhost:3000/rails/info/routes` を確認してみて欲しいのですが、
`POST /line_items/:id(.:format)` というルートが多分存在しないと思います。
GET ではなく POST であることに注意してください。

要するに `routes.rb` の `resources :line_items` だけでは今回のような ID を指定したPOST は出来ません。

そもそも Rails は `LineItemsController#create` に対しては `LineItem` を新規に作ることを想定しています。
なので、`LineItem` は存在しないはずなのに、IDを指定したURLになるのは設計上何かがおかしいです。

https://railsguides.jp/routing.html#%E3%83%8D%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%83%AA%E3%82%BD%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9
を参照して欲しいのですが、ネストしたモデルの作成ちょっと特殊で

例えばカートにアイテムを追加する場合
`POST /carts/:cart_id/line_item` のようなルートで、 `LineItem#create` を呼んであげるのが一般的です。

ただ、今回の場合は`Cart#add_item` を呼び出す形にしたいと思うので、

`POST /carts/:cart_id/add_item` というルートで、
URLとしては `/carts/2/add_item?item_id=2` のような形になり、

コントローラーはに `CartsController#add_item` メソッドを追加し、その中で `Cart#add_item` メソッドを実行してあげる形になるのかな。と思います。

ネストしたモデルの作成について全てここには書ききれないので、入れ子、ネストなどのワードを組み合わせて調べてみてください。

Answer (score 0):

@sinzanmono46 さん、こんにちは。

show.html.rb がItemかLineItemか判断できなかったのですが、一般的に「商品ページ」である items#show だとして回答します。

まず、button_toで指定しているpathがroutesに存在しないのは、 @HAZI さんの指摘どおりだとおもいます。

```
<%= button_to '買い物カゴに追加する',line_item_path(item_id:@item), class: 'button is-warning add-to-cart' %>
```

ここで`LineItems#create`を呼び出したいのであれば、Rails的には、以下のような感じにすると自然なのかなとおもいました。

**app\controllers\items_controller.rb**

```
def show
  @cart ||= Cart.find_or_create_by!(id:session[:cart_id])
  session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
  @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  @line_item = LineItem.new
end
```

**app\views\items\show.html.erb**

```
<%= form_with url: line_items_path, model: @line_item, local: true do |form| %>
  <%= form.hidden_field :item_id, value: @item.id %>
  <%= form.hidden_field :cart_id, value: @cart.id %>
  <%= form.submit '買い物カゴに追加する' %>
<% end %>
```